# antd table scroll up on pagination click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

this is my table code in AntD, On pagination clicked I want it to scroll to page top. I tried using [BackTop](https://ant.design/components/back-top/) but I couldn't figure out how to do that with pagination

```
const GenericTable = props => {
const { withHeader, pagination, showTable, error } = props;
return (
  <Fragment>
    {withHeader && <TableHeader {...props} />}
     {showTable && (
      <CustomTable
        {...props}
        pagination={{
          ...pagination,
          showTotal,
        }}
      />
    )}
    <TableFooter>{<Error>{error}</Error>}</TableFooter>
  </Fragment>
);
};
GenericTable.defaultProps = {
 pagination: {
 pageSize: 10,
 },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Antd's table have a onChange method, by using that you can scroll to top by java script.

use

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

CodeSanbox Link
[Antd's table scroll top on pagination](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2z8o22m2o)

You can always store pagination in state and compare it to latest one, to avoid scroll of table on changing of anything else in table like filter or sorting.

I hope this would help.

Thanks

Comment: The pagination component also has a onChange property. You can improve the solution calling the proposed code from there. https://ant.design/components/pagination/